# How to install Account confirmation and password recovery with .NET Core Identity ones the project it is already created

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know that the way to install the authentication package through **Identity** it is checking "User individual login".

My problem it is that I already created a project and I do not know how to enable the **Identity .NET CORE**.

I was not able to find any command that let me modify my already created project. For me it is important to not delete my project because I already did a lot of progress but I need a login now that can enable me to lock certain methods and actions.

Thank you

Comment: Create a new one in a different directory and compare the differences to see what they are, and then manually copy those into your new project?

Comment: You could use [Scaffold Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to add and view the generated files to review the template interaction with Identity, check [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGQxa.png). Then, refer [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to configure your application use Identity. You can also create a new project with `User individual login`, then according to it to change your code.

Comment: Thank you @ZhiLv for your answer. That worked for me!

Comment: Hi @BranMartinez, glad to hear it did help resolve the problem. And I add it as an answer, hoping it can help other community members quickly fix similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to add and view the generated files to review the template interaction with Identity, check this picture:

[image]

Then, refer [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to configure your application use Identity.

Besides, you can also create a new project with `User individual login`, then according to it to change your code.